Blow up of terminal singularity and canonical singularity
A normal singularity $(X,x)$ over a field $k$ is terminal (resp. canonical) if
$(i)$
it it is $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein.   and
$(ii)$For any resolution of singularity $F:Y\rightarrow X$,
$K_Y-f^*K_X>0$(resp. $\geqq 0$)
My question is as follows.
Let $\pi:Bl_x(X)\rightarrow X$ be a blow up of $X$ at $x$.
1.Then is $Bl_x(X)$ terminal (canonical)?
2.  In the case 1 does not hold, is  there exist a normal variety $Y$ which has at most terminal ( canonical) singularity and birational morphism $\pi :Y\rightarrow X$ s.t the pullback of the ideal  $m_{X,x}O_Y$ is invertiblle .
2 always hold if characteristic of k is zero because there is always resolution of singularity.

I assume 1. does not hold but I'd have to think hard to find an example.  2. is open outside of when we know resolution of singularities holds (ie, char 0 or dim $\leq 3$).  If you can weaken $\pi$ birational to $\pi$ and alteration (I assume you want $\pi$ to be proper/projective) then you can make $Y$ nonsingular.

That's the first time I've heard about alteration .
Thank you.

The origin of the hypersurface defined by
$$x_0^2 + x_1^4 + x_2^4 + \cdots + x_n^4 = 0$$
is a canonical singularity for $n = 3$, and a terminal singularity for $n \ge 4$ (see e.g. Theorem 2 in this paper). The blowup at the origin is defined by
$$x_0^2 + x_1^2(1 + x_2^4 + \cdots x_n^4) = 0$$
in some local chart, which is singular in codimension $1$ and therefore non-normal.
The case $n=3$ is already mentioned in Miles Reid's "Canonical 3-folds".
